# How can I specify the size and position of a plot area in inches?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, charts, microsoft-powerpoint-2016

When I highlight a chart area, I get these options:

[image]

However, when I highlight a plot area, I don't get the "size & properties" options any longer:

[image]

My issue is that I have the same type of chart with different data on several slides and the **height and width of all the plot areas is inconsistent** (however, the chart areas all have the same size & position).

How can I adjust the plot areas **exactly (with numbers)**, rather than having to eyeball them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite a startling omission, isn't it?

A little VBA may help:

```
Sub SizePlotArea()
    Dim oSld As Slide
    Dim oCht As Chart

    Set oCht = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Chart

    With oCht.PlotArea
    ' Edit these values as needed
    ' Change the following lines to e.g. Msgbox .Left etc
    ' to get the values of the chart you want to match others TO
        .Left = 50
        .Top = 50
        .Height = 400
        .Width = 400
    End With

End Sub
```

NOTE:  The dimensions for .Left, .Top etc are in Points, the unit PPT uses for most programmable functions. 72 points to the inch.

If you prefer, you could do something like:

```
.Height = 72 * 5.25
```

to set the .Height to 5.25 inches.